# How to write custom annotation for field which will create custom setter for that field?

Tags: java, annotations, getter-setter, lombok

I have follwing class.

```
public class X {
    private int a1;
    private int a2;
    private int a3;
    private int a4;
    .
    .
    .
    private int a100;
    // name of fields are different in actual class(but there are sure 100 fields)
}
```

Now I don't want to assign negative value to any of int field. So for doing that I have to write setter for all of that(It will boaring to write setter(which will only set positive value) for all fields).

So is there way which will reduce my effort, like by writing custome annotation(which will generat setter for that field, setter must set only positive value and ignore nagative value) and apply that annonation to all the field.

While looking into "How to write custom annotation in java", I found that we can write annotation for field(which assign default value for that field), for methods, But getting nothing for "**custome annotation for fields which will create setter for that fields**".

Note:- I also looked into [lombok setter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter), but it only generate normal setter, not custom setter as I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, you can add a new setter template for this.

Put the cursor in your class, and go to Code -> Generate. In the menu, select "Setter". Then tap on the "..." on the top right of this menu:

[image]

Then you can add a new template called "no negatives" with the following code:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
  if ($paramName >= 0) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
    $field.name = $paramName;
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("$paramName must be positive");
  }
}
```

Note that this template does not check for whether the type of field can be compared to 0 or not.

I basically modified the IntelliJ default template by adding the if statement:

```
if ($paramName >= 0) {
```

and the else branch:

```
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("$paramName must be positive");
  }
```

If you just want to not set the field when the parameter is negative, instead of throwing an exception, just remove the else branch.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for creating annotation so that I don't have to write setter at all(just like when we use lombok, we don't have to write setter, it will generate all at complie time), Is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: If I will not able to find what I am looking for, then I will definitely use this.

Comment: @yajiv I had a look at lombok and it doesn't seem like it provides much customisation of the body of your setter. You'll have to find a more powerful tool or just use IntelliJ templates.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I am alos looking if I can find, otherwise I will IntelliJ templates

Comment: This is much easier than writing a custom annotation and a compile time annotation processor that has to code gen your classes.